# LoadByUsername not called (Spring Security 4.1.4)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying a "basic" security configuration with SPRING 4.1.4 RELEASE.

I need : 
- A custom login;
- Authentication with database (Hibernate as ORM);

I'm simply trying to login succesfully and then display a home page.
The login page appears, but as i authenticate myself, i get error 404.

I post my whole configuration:

**login.jsp :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="ENTER"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

**SecurityConfig** :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home",true).failureUrl("/access_denied")
    .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
    .accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public Md5PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

**Security Initializer**

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
```

}

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    GenericDAO daoU = (GenericDAO) VisibleApplicationContext.getBean("daoUser");
    com.aconti.stemunitcore.model.User u=
            (com.aconti.stemunitcore.model.User) daoU.readByPropertyLike("username", username).get(0);
    String password=u.getPassword();

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Role role: u.getRoles()){
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getDescription()));
    }

    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User springUser = 
            new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, authorities); 
    return springUser;
}
```

}

**AppConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.aconti.stemunit4.*" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
              = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

}

**SpringMVCInitializer**

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer
extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

WTF, totally... i've wasted 4 hours on this, including 15 min for posting on stackoverflow, and then i figured it out a way to solve this.

I modified the form action from -- > action="/login" to --> action="/MyContextPath/login".

Now, debugging, the loadbyusername gets called. Can someone explain why?